# Maven Dependency conflict issue

Tags: maven

I have a Project A which depends on Project B.

I developed B separately.

B depends on xml-apis jar 1.4.01

A depends on xml-apis jar 2.0.2

When B use xml-apis jar 1.4.01 the infamous error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/dom/ElementTraversal comes up.

When A use xml-apis jar 1.4.01 I get a cascade of error that don't even want to try to fix.

A is a project that i am slightly customizing.

What can i do ? nothing ? need to change B.

Best,

Daniel

Comment: Well You can refactor one or other to use the same dependency. Thats because on the final release where A and B will be on the same classpath there is no guarantee that the classloader will load one over another it is defined by the OS file order. The other way is so painfull that you probably will prefer the refactor (which is create your own classloader).

Answer (score 1):

Indeed you have basically 3 options:

1. Either modify B so that it can work with xml-apis 2.0.2
2. Or modify A so that it can work with xml-apis 1.4.01
3. Or use a framework like OSGI, which allows the loading of different version of libraries at the same time in the same VM (in different classloaders)

Either way, you will unfortunately have a lot of work...
I think you can try to approach the one which requires the least changes...